# Convert column values to grouped comma-separated string

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table like below:

```
ID  Name 
1   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

I want output like below:

```
ID  Name
1   a,b
2   c
3   d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, (select itbl.name+','
            from tblname itbl
            where itbl.id=tbl.id
            for xml path('')) name
from tblname tbl
group by id
```

Comment: @Aaron, oops, I was changing table names while typing it, fixed!

Comment: This also produces an extra trailing comma. You can eliminate this with `REPLACE` (as in my answer) or put the comma first and use `STUFF((select ',' + itbl.name ...), 1, 1, '');`

Comment: To be fair your solution clobbers any spaces already existing in `name`, but you don't see me nit-picking... In the grand scheme of things, it's easier to just always remove a trailing comma in your controller than figuring out which comma is actually a space.

Comment: I'm not nit-picking, just pointing out that it's different than the OP's requirements. I even told you how to correct it (and corrected mine). Don't be so defensive.

Comment: Aaron, Your response is not according to my requirement. Reason - I did not ask for XML...

Comment: @Pankaj it never returned XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Names = STUFF((SELECT N',' + Name
  FROM dbo.TheTable AS x
  WHERE x.ID = t.ID
  ORDER BY Name
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1,1,'')
FROM dbo.TheTable AS t
GROUP BY ID;
```

On more modern versions (SQL Server 2017+), this is much tidier and more efficient:

```
SELECT ID, Names = STRING_AGG(Name, N',')
  FROM dbo.TheTable
  GROUP BY ID;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3fa022f753d70d7136c4a80d75efbf90)